# If-Else condition not getting detected in Google Apps Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I am looping over the list "res_1" and when the Id is "400" then need to multiply "Total_Weight" with variable "cost_400"; else if the id is "400W", then need to multiply "Total_Weight"
with variable "cost_400W". In the end, "result" array should contain "Vendor" and correspoding number ("Total_Weight" * "cost_400").

In the code below, I loop over "res_1", but for some reason, the if condition is not getting detected and it does not go inside the corresponding if or else if condition.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Expected result:

```
result = [['ABC',42341820 ],['DEF',91734000]]
```

Input:

```
res_1:

[ { Id: '400 ', Vendor: 'ABC', Total_Weight: 32322 },
  { Id: '400W ', Vendor: 'DEF', Total_Weight: 61156 } ]

var cost_400 = 1310
var cost_400W = 1500

res_1.forEach((r2,i2)=>{
  if (r2['Id'] == "400" ) {
    Logger.log(r2['Total_Weight']*cost_400)
  }
  else if (r2['Id'] == "400W" ) {
    Logger.log(r2['Total_Weight']*cost_400W)
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `res_1=[ { Id: '400 ', Vendor: 'ABC', Total_Weight: 32322 }, { Id: '400W ', Vendor: 'DEF', Total_Weight: 61156 } ];`?

Comment: There appears to be a space at the end of each Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

1. Extra space on the res_1. `if (r2['Id'] == "400" )` and `if (r2['Id'] == "400W" )` will always get false because `'400 '` is not equal to `'400'` and `'400W '` is not equal to `'400W'`.

**Solution:**

1. If you cannot manipulate the output of res, you can use `String.match()` and reverse the if else statement. The reason for reversal is that `String.match(400)` can catch both `400` and `400W` and if we start with String.match('400W') we can prevent the method from catching `400`.

Your code should look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var res_1=
  [ { Id: '400 ', Vendor: 'ABC', Total_Weight: 32322 },
    { Id: '400W ', Vendor: 'DEF', Total_Weight: 61156 } ]

  var cost_400 = 1310
  var cost_400W = 1500

  res_1.forEach((r2,i2)=>{
    if (r2['Id'].match("400W")) {
      Logger.log(r2['Total_Weight']*cost_400W)
    }
    else if (r2['Id'].match("400")) { 
      Logger.log(r2['Total_Weight']*cost_400)
    }
  });
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)